# When setting a variable in python, why does the order matter?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def calculate_error(m, b, point):
    x_point, y_point = point  
    y = m*x_point + b
    distance = abs(y-y_point)
    return distance

print(calculate_error(2, 0, (5, 5)))
```

I ran the code above and it worked. But I do not understand why it doesn't work when I switched the order and tried setting point = x_point, y_point

instead?

Comment: Why *would* you expect it to work after changing the order?

Comment: After all, this is a programming language, and while its syntax is not strict, it still exists.

Answer (score 2):

Because :

```
y_point, x_point = point
```

Is setting two variables to two constants (five and five)

```
point = x_point, y_point
```

Is attempting to set one variable to two other variables.